# Swift: "unrecognized selector" when access a property that exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm importing an old library written in Objective C as a submodule in my Swift project.
When trying to access a property of an object of that library, the app crashes with an "unrecognized selector" exception.

This is the code for the Objective C class:

```
@interface MotionzoneItem : NSObject<NSCopying>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *describe;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL move, enabled;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect frame;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint point0, point1, point2, point3;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint leftTop, rightTop, rightBottom, leftBottom;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint selectedPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *handleColor;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger index;

- (CGPoint)getSelectedPointWithRect:(CGRect)targetFrame;
- (CGRect)getCircleFrameWithPoint:(CGPoint)targetPoint;
- (void)updateFrame:(CGPoint)targetPoint;
- (void)resetItem;

@end
```

If I check the Swift-class generated, we can see the same properties:

```
open class MotionzoneItem : NSObject, NSCopying {

open var title: String!
open var describe: String! { get }
open var move: Bool
open var enabled: Bool
open var frame: CGRect
open var point0: CGPoint { get }
open var point1: CGPoint { get }
open var point2: CGPoint { get }
open var point3: CGPoint { get }
open var leftTop: CGPoint { get }
open var rightTop: CGPoint { get }
open var rightBottom: CGPoint { get }
open var leftBottom: CGPoint { get }
open var selectedPoint: CGPoint { get }
open var handleColor: UIColor!
open var index: UInt

open func getSelectedPoint(with targetFrame: CGRect) -> CGPoint
open func getCircleFrame(with targetPoint: CGPoint) -> CGRect
open func updateFrame(_ targetPoint: CGPoint)
open func resetItem()

}
```

Everything seems to be OK, but then, in the code, when I try to execute this command:

```
let motionzoneItem: MotionzoneItem = MotionzoneItem.init()
motionzoneItem.handleColor = UIColor.red
```

A exception is fired saying: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MotionzoneItem handleColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742ed700'`

And if I check the object through the inspector, I can see there are a lot of properties not included in the object:

[image: Inspector debug]

Where are the other properties, like *handleColor* or *title*???

Thanks!

**Note:** If I execute the same code written in Objective C instead of Swift, it works.

Comment: Hmm. Are you 100% sure that's the offending line, because you'd get "-[MotionzoneItem setHandleColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to ..." message in that case (note, that's `setHandleColor`, not `handleColor` in the error). The error is saying that it cannot find `handleColor`, but you're not call that on this line. You're calling `setHandleColor`...

Comment: The key is in the `'-[MotionzoneItem handleColor]:` I think showing some more codes would help???

Comment: I'd suggest you create a [minimal, reproducible yet verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because it's hard for us to help you if we can't reproduce it. And we don't need to see all of `MotionzoneItem`. Create a copy of your project, prune out everything that is unrelated (e.g. everything except `handleColor` related stuff) and make sure you can still reproduce the problem.

Comment: And just to confirm, you don't have anything like `@dynamic handleColor` in your `@implementation` do you? That can prevent the accessor methods from being synthesized for you. (Then again, if you did, it wouldn't work if called it from Objective-C.)

Comment: Re: dynamic properties, there is zero reason why you should assume that because an object exposes a property, it stores that property in value. The absence of `handleColor` and `title` as identifiable values in memory means nothing. When you issue a call to `handleColor` you say "do whatever you have to do to give me the handle colour". You don't say "I mandate that you must now fetch and return a stored value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIXED**

At the end, cleaning the project and removing everything in the Derived Data folder fix the issue. Now everything works as expected and I can see all the MotionzoneItem properties.

Sorry for the inconveniences this may cause and many thanks for your help.

Comment: i have the same issue for 2 properties (objc), while accessing this from swift, it cause crash: `[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`